# I writed a .bat script on windows to get last update of some remote computers and I can't test it because i don't have acces right now

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am a trainee in Software company.
I have been asked to right a bat script to check the last Reboot of some computers on the network. I writed this script but I have no way to test I have no access to those computers. 
Can Any one test it for me please or correct it for me.
Thank you very much.

```
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%a in (List_computers.txt) do call :Get_Last_Reboot %%a
goto :end

:Get_Last_Reboot
set serv=%1
wmic /node:%serv% OS get csname >> Liste_Last_Reboot.txt
wmic /node:%serv% OS get LastBootUpTime >> Liste_Last_Reboot.txt
:end
```

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand the question.

Comment: So you want people to do your job for you.  StackOverFlow is here to help you with your code.  We are not here to write code for you or test code for you.  Why don't you test it by putting your computer in the computer list. One code tip.  You certainly don't need to put all of that code into a separate function.  Just do it all in the FOR command. It will run a lot faster.

Comment: should be possible without a `for` loop and give `List_computers.txt` directly to `wmic`. See `wmic /node /?`

Comment: I understand . Thank you for answering. I taught it was ok to ask those kind of stuff. It's my first post I am sorry.

Comment: Do you think that this script will work because i need it to be functional and I have no way to test it. Thank you very much for the answers

Comment: Test using your own machine. `wmic /NODE:localhost OS GET LastBootUpTime`. The account under which this is run must have permission to access this information on the other machines.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a list of turned on computers.

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A > ComputerList.txt
```

This will use wmic to query all computers in the list.

```
wmic /node:@"c:\computerlist.txt" /failfast:on /output:"C:\Liste_Last_Reboot.txt" os get lastbootuptime /format:csv
```

To test a WMIC command omit the node and it will run on your machine. You can also use `127.0.0.1` as an IP address. This is always the machine it is typed on.

See

```
wmic /?

wmic /node /?

wmic /failfast /?

wmic /output /?

wmic /format /?

wmic os /?

wmic os get /?
```

Comment: Thank you very much